# Django loop is returning multiple posts

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, jinja2

I am trying to get django to display posts from a single catgory on that category's page, instead, it displays all the categories and the posts under each category in the template.

Here are my models (I trimmed them down):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ...
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Title", null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)


class Petition(models.Model):
    ...
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name="Category", related_name='petitions')
    ...
```

## `views.py`:

```
class CategoryMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context


class CategoryView(CategoryMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Category
    categories = Category.objects.all() # this will get all categories, you can do some filtering if you need (e.g. excluding categories without posts in it)
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    template_name = 'petition/category_list.html'


class CategoryIndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'petition/category.html'
    context_object_name = 'category_list'

    def get_queryset(self): 
        return Category.objects.prefetch_related('petitions').order_by('-created_on')[:10]



class PetitionIndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'petition/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'petition_list'
    queryset = Petition.objects.order_by('-created_on')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset_list = Petition.objects.order_by('-created_on')

        #SEARCH QUERY LOGIC
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
                Q(title__icontains = query) |
                Q(petition__icontains = query) |
                Q(created_by__first_name__icontains = query) | #icontains = only text fields. Use text field within foreign key field
                Q(created_by__last_name__icontains = query) 
                ).distinct()

        paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10) # Show 10 posts per page
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            queryset = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
            queryset = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
            queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        return queryset

        context = {
        'object_list' : queryset,
        'title' : 'List'
        }
```

## `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^$',views.PetitionIndexView.as_view(), name="homepage"),
url(r'^petition/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',views.DetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
url(r'^categories/$', views.CategoryView.as_view(), name='category_list'),
url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',views.CategoryIndexView.as_view(), name="category_detail"),
```

And my template (category.html for the CategoryIndexView) is in this format,

## `category.html`:

```
{% for category in category_list %}
    {% for petition in category.petitions.all %}
        ...
        {{ petition.title }}
        ...
    {% end for %}
{% end for %}
```

This shows posts in Category A, B and C in the same template.

With the views I set, how can I get it to show only posts for category A when category A is clicked?

Also, the ordering is not working properly. It is not adhering to the ordering I gave it in the view

Comment: Does the django loop in the template execute every time you change category? I'm guessing so, in that case, does the category list variable change according to the category you just switched to?

Comment: Please show your URLs.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have added the URLs

Comment: @Strinnityk yes the loop executes everytime I change category but the content displayed is the same regardless of which category page I am on.

Comment: Which of those views is the one that is supposed to be doing this? Which view does that template refer to?

Comment: @DanielRoseman it is the category.html template for the CategoryIndexView. I have edited the question to indicate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong view class. A ListView is to show a list of instances of the class; so a CategoryIndexView would be to show the list of categories. But you don't want a list of categories; you want a single category, along with a list of its petitions. So, you should use a DetailView.

```
class CategoryDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'petition/category.html'
    context_object_name = 'category'

    def get_queryset(self): 
        return Category.objects.prefetch_related('petitions')
```

And the template is just:

```
{% for petition in category.petitions.all %}
    ...
    {{ petition.title }}
    ...
{% end for %}
```

Edit: I changed the context_object_name from 'category_list' to 'category' and the template is returning the right posts now.

Comment: It's working like a charm now. My error was in duplicating the 'ListViews'. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that every time you change categories, the whole loop executes again, without changing the contents of `category_list` (which initially is ["A", "B", "C"]). In that case, even though you click on the button to change category, the loops displays the contents of the categories "A", "B" and "C" again regardless.

Have you tried adding an if statement that checks in which category you are at the moment and only show the posts in that category?

```
{% for category in category_list %}
  {% if category.name == ACTUAL_CATEGORY_TO_DISPLAY %}
    {% for petition in category.petitions.all %}
      ...
      {{ petition.title }}
      ...
     {% end for %}
  {% end if %}
{% end for %}
```

Edit:

As @Daniel Roseman pointed out in a comment, this is a quite inefficient solution. I've just posted it because I'm guessing if this is really what is happening to you.

If this is the case you shouldn't be doing this. One of the proper solutions is making a new request that retrieves all the posts for that given category every time you change it.

Anyhow, I'm just guessing here. For us to give you a better insight you should post the template code that does the category change.

Comment: While this would work, it's a very inefficient solution to the problem. Why loop over categories you don't want in the first place? The filtering should be done in the view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm aware of that, it's just the fastest solution it's come to mind without knowing how the category change is done.